# Split multidimensional array into single array

Tags: php, arrays

I have this kind of an array:-

```
$result=Array([city] => xyz [name] => Array( [0] => Xyz1 [1] => xyz2 ) [email] => Array ( [0] => xyz1@gmail.com [1] => xyz2@gmail.com ) [phone] => Array ( [0] => 23423423-1 [1] => 23423423-2 ) [address] => Array ( [0] => xyz1 [1] => xyz2 ) [dis] => xyz);
```

and i want this like

```
$r1=Array ( [city] => xyz [name] => xyz1 [email] => xyz1@gmail.com [phone] => 23423423-1 [address] => xyz1 [dis] => xyz );  
$r2=Array ([city] => xyz [name] => xyz2 [email] => xyz2@gmail.com [phone] => 23423423-2 [address] => xyz2 [city] => xyz );
```

Comment: You going to want to do a recursive loop, checking if each key is and array before pushing it to a new array. i.e. foreach($result as $key => $value){//check if key is array and take action

Answer (score 1):

This assumes that you will have more than one array to process and simply sorts your elements into a new, formatted array.

```
<?php
$results = array(
    array(
        'city' => 'xyz',
        'name' => array( 'Xyz1', 'xyz2' ),
        'email' => array( 'xyz1@gmail.com', 'xyz2@gmail.com' ),
        'phone' => array( '23423423-1', '23423423-2' ),
        'address' => array( 'xyz1', 'xyz2' ),
        'dis' => 'xyz'
    )
);

$formatted_results = array();


foreach( $results as $result ) {

    foreach( array(0,1) as $key ) {
        $formatted_results[][$key] = array(
        'city' => $result['city'],
        'name' => $result['name'][$key],
        'email' => $result['email'][$key],
        'phone' => $result['phone'][$key],
        'address' => $result['address'][$key],
        'dis' => $result['dis']
        );
    }

}

echo "<pre>";

print_r($formatted_results);
```

This will output

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [city] => xyz
                    [name] => Xyz1
                    [email] => xyz1@gmail.com
                    [phone] => 23423423-1
                    [address] => xyz1
                    [dis] => xyz
                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [city] => xyz
                    [name] => xyz2
                    [email] => xyz2@gmail.com
                    [phone] => 23423423-2
                    [address] => xyz2
                    [dis] => xyz
                )

        )

)
```

You can then access your new values like this:

```
foreach( $formatted_results as $value ) {
    $r1 = $value[0];
    $r2 = $value[1];
}
```

Or if you only have the single array:

```
$r1 = $formatted_results[0][0];
$r2 = $formatted_results[0][1];
```